# Can not send livy rest api using proxy user into kerberized hadoop cluster

Tags: rest, hadoop, kerberos, impersonation, livy

We want to use proxyuser in livy rest api for processing the data in kerberized hadoop cluster.
i.e. we want to impersonate user roslinda.statistik with livy user as below

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "X-Requested-By: admin" -d '{"name":"ros-1","proxyUser":"roslinda.silastik"}' --negotiate -u : http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8999/sessions -v
```

and we got error as below

```
* Closing connection 0
"User 'livy' not allowed to impersonate 'Some(roslinda.silastik)'."
```

in ambari we've set livy.impersonation.enabled to true

How can we impersonate user using main user or secondary main user (i.e. admin) in livy?